# Windows mounted Devices

Tags: usb-flash-drive, mount

```
/dev/sdb1
```

This is an example of a mounted USB key under Linux. It's a file that can be viewed as hexa, edited, .. etc, but not used to manipulate device via serial communication protocol.

Simply, Can you provide me with a same path under Windows ?
In other words, where does windows saving mounted devices files !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you provide me with a same path under Windows ?

Yes, `\\.\PhysicalDrive1`.

Not all programs can access such paths, however. I've been using [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) myself.

**See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/424375/1686)** for more detailed information on how Windows treats disks.

---

Every disk, partition, and volume has several names under `\Device` in the [NT namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). For example:

- (NT) `\Device\Harddisk0\DR0` – first hard disk (entire disk)
- (NT) `\Device\Harddisk0\Partition0` – first hard disk (entire disk)
- (NT) `\Device\Harddisk1\Partition1` – second hard disk, first partition
- (NT) `\Device\Floppy0` – first floppy drive
- (NT) `\Device\HarddiskVolume1` – first *volume* (usually a partition, but it's possible to have a single volume spanning multiple disks, similar to LVM in Linux)
- (NT) `\ArcName\multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(1)partition(3)` – second hard disk, third partition (using an ARC name)

They are accessible from [Win32 device namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) by prefixing `\\.\GLOBALROOT`, such as `\\.\GLOBALROOT\Device\Floppy0` and so on.

The Win32 device namespace, `\\.\`, also has symbolic links to specific devices, for more convenient usage. For example:

- (Win32) `\\.\C:` – volume by its drive letter
- (Win32) `\\.\Volume{93e657ad-64a8-11df-b394-806d6172685f}` – volume by its GUID
- (Win32) `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` – entire physical disk

(The paths which point to volumes also work in the Win32 *file* namespace `\\?\`: for example, `\\?\Volume{93e657ad-64a8-11df-b394-806d6172685f}\WINDOWS\Notepad.exe` or `\\?\C:\Program Files`. The Win32 file namespace can be used to bypass the 253 character limit in file names, as described in the [namespace article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).)

---

You can see the NT namespace with [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx). (The Win32 device namespace is accessible in WinObj too, in the directory (NT) `\GLOBAL??\`.)

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim: I updated the answer a little – I had mixed up the namespace prefixes; it should have been `\\.\ `, not `\\?\ `. (Also, in WinObj, \ is the NT namespace, and \GLOBAL?? is the Win32 namespace.)